# Livewire: select items from Frontend to pass to Backend

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have this form on a livewire component that sends a query to the method `cotizar()`, fetchs the result, treats the data and saves the result so I can show at the frontend.
Let's say, the result has ten differentts items. At this first moment, I wwant to select just two and send them to the client via e-mail.
To be able to select some items and send them back to the controller, I need to create a new method and insert some hidden fields so the form can send via POST, right?
Well, that's what a normal form should do, but this is a livewire and I just can't make it work at all.

Let's se some code:

At the top of the livewire class:

```
    public $cotacaos = [];
    public $total = [];
    public $cotacaoLogoOper;
    public $cotacaoNomeOper;
    public $cotacaoOperId;
    public $cotacaoNomePlano;
    public $cotacaoPlano;
    public $cotacaoIdade;
    public $cotacaoPlanoTotal;
```

```
public function cotizar()
    {
        $this->salvarCotacao($this->cotacao, $this->leadId, $this->userId);
            
        $idades = explode(',', $this->cotacao);
        $cotacaos = [];

        // Criar uma instância da classe CotacaoHelper
        $cotacaoHelper = new CotacaoHelper();

        // Encontrar os IDs dos planos que têm o campo publico_id igual a $this->publicos
        $planosIds = Plano::where('publico_id', $this->publico)->where('tipo_id', $this->tipo)->pluck('id');

        // Filtrar os preços na tabela precos que contenham o id = plano_id de precos
        $precos = Preco::whereIn('plano_id', $planosIds)->where('vigencia', '<=', today())->get();

        foreach ($idades as $idade) {
            if (strpos($idade, 'x') !== false) {
                $precos_total = $cotacaoHelper->calcularPrecoMultiplo($idade, $precos);
            } else {
                $precos_total = $cotacaoHelper->calcularPrecoSimples($idade, $precos);
            }
            if ($precos_total) {
                foreach ($precos_total as $preco_total) {
                    $cotacaos[] = [
                        'idade' => $idade . ' anos',
                        'preco' => $preco_total['preco'],
                        'plano' => $preco_total['plano'],
                        'nome' => $preco_total['nomeProduto'],
                        'logotipo'  => $preco_total['logotipo'],
                        'operadora' => $preco_total['operadora'],
                        'operadora_id' => $preco_total['operadora_id'],
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        $cotacaosAgrupados = $cotacaoHelper->groupCotacoesByOperadora($cotacaos);
        foreach ($cotacaosAgrupados as &$operadora) {
            $operadora['total'] = $cotacaoHelper->calcularTotalOperadora($operadora);
        }

        $this->cotacaos = $cotacaosAgrupados;
    }
```

It does all this treatment to the result and save it in `$this->cotacaos`. So far, so good.
So at the blade witch renders the livewire component, I have this:

```
@if ($cotacaos)
        <form wire:submit.prevent="enviarCotacao">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                @foreach($cotacaos as $operadora => $planos)
                <li class="media cotacao">
                    <img class="mr-3" src="images/{{ $planos['logotipo'] }}" alt="" style="max-width: 50px;">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <!-- Adiciona campos hidden para o nome da operadora e seu id -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="cotacaoOperId{{ $planos['cotacoes'][0]['operadora_id'] }}" wire:model="cotacaoOperId" wire:initial-value="{{ $planos['cotacoes'][0]['operadora_id'] }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cotacaoLogoOper" wire:model="cotacaoLogoOper" wire:initial-value="images/{{ $planos['logotipo'] }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cotacaoNomeOper" wire:model="{{ $planos['operadora'] }}" wire:initial-value="{{ $planos['operadora'] }}">
                        <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">{{ $planos['operadora'] }}<input type="checkbox" wire:initial-value="{{ $operadora }}"
                                id="{{ $planos['cotacoes'][0]['operadora_id'] }}"></h5>
                        @foreach($planos['cotacoes'] as $plano)
                        <strong>{{ $plano['nome'] }}:</strong> <br>
                        {{ $plano['plano'] }} - {{ $plano['idade'] }} para a(s) idade(s): <span
                            class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">{{ $plano['preco'] }}</span>
                        <hr>
                        <!-- Adiciona campos hidden para o nome do plano, plano, idade e total do plano -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="cotacaoNomePlano" wire:model="cotacaoNomePlano" wire:initial-value="{{ $plano['nome'] }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cotacaoPlano" wire:model="cotacaoPlano" wire:initial-value="{{ $plano['plano'] }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cotacaoIdade" wire:model="cotacaoIdade" wire:initial-value="{{ $plano['idade'] }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cotacaoPlano" wire:model="cotacaoPlano" wire:initial-value="{{ $plano['preco'] }}">
                        @endforeach
                        <input type="hidden" name="cotacaoPlanoTotal" wire:model="cotacaoPlanoTotal" wire:initial-value="{{ $planos['total'] }}">
                        <span class="badge badge-success"><strong>Total:</strong> R$ {{ $planos['total'] }}</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Enviar por e-mail</button>
        </form>
        @endif
```

I don't know if there is a "livewire" way to send data to a method, but as far as I remember, that's it in HTML.
My GOAL here is:
From the frontend, the user should be able to select one or more results and send them back to the controller, to a `sendMail()` method, but it is not working.
I am completely LOST here.
Need help, please!

Answer (score 0):

I got it!
First, don't need those hidden fields.
Second, need to declare a public empty array.
Then, need to get the index of the array position and pass it to the empty array, so I can compare it with `$this->cotacaos`.

Kinda work!